# How can i make my slider controls stay at the same position

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I have this slider in my website with multiple slides and different text nebeath it for each slide. The problem is that the controls go up and down a bit when the text is longer..... see here, http://prntscr.com/5d2veh . How can I make my controls stay at the center of the picture in the middle?

Thanks, a lot!

P.S. If you see a thing in my question which isnt well explained or anything please tell me so I can make a better question next time :)

Code:

```
<!-- Locations -->
<div class="panel-box">
    <div class="titles">
        <h4>Clubs</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- Locations Carousel -->
    <ul class="single-carousel" id="loc-carousel">
        <li>
            <img src="static/img/blog/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" >
            <div class="info-single-carousel">
                <h4>Rijssen</h4>
                <p><b>Risnestars</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="static/img/blog/2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="info-single-carousel">
                <h4>Hengelo</h4>
                <p><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="static/img/blog/3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="info-single-carousel">
                <h4>Oldenzaal</h4>
                <p><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="static/img/blog/3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="info-single-carousel">
                <h4>Enschede</h4>
                <p><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br><b>Clubnaam</b><br>Adres<br>Plaatsnaam, Postcode<br>Telefoonnummer<br><br></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Locations Carousel -->
</div>
<!-- End Locations -->
```

CSS:

```
/*
*   Owl Carousel Owl Demo Theme 
*   v1.22
*/

.owl-theme .owl-controls{
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Styling Next and Prev buttons */

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Clickable class fix problem with hover on touch devices */
/* Use it for non-touch hover action */
.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-buttons div:hover{
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Styling Pagination*/

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page{
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span{ /* es este pilas*/
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 5px 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page.active span,
.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-page:hover span{
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
    opacity: 1;
}

/* If PaginationNumbers is true */

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span.owl-numbers{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

/* preloading images */

.owl-item.loading{
    min-height: 190px;
    background: url(AjaxLoader.gif) no-repeat center center
}


/* Styling Next and Prev buttons  Titles -----------------------------*/

.single-carousel  .owl-prev,
.single-carousel .owl-next{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.single-carousel:hover .owl-prev,
.single-carousel:hover .owl-next{
    opacity: 1;
}
.single-carousel .owl-prev{
    left: -5px;
}
.single-carousel  .owl-next{
    right:-5px;
}

.owl-controls{
    margin: 0;
}
.twitter .owl-theme .owl-controls{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#blog-post  .owl-prev,
#blog-post .owl-next{   
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

- Edit - 1
     In the CSS owl-prev and owl-next are the controls. A Javascript plugin makes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the controls are positioned using a percentage:

```
.single-carousel  .owl-prev,
.single-carousel .owl-next{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%; // <--- this one
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

As it is a percentage of the wrapping container, larger containers will mean a larger value for the top attribute.

If you know that the height of the img is always going to be the same you could set them to be a set value, such as:

```
.single-carousel  .owl-prev,
.single-carousel .owl-next{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Without knowing what the markup is like after the plugin has parsed the DOM and altered the markup it is hard to say if there is another way of positioning these relative to the `img` or carousel, to allow for a percentage width to make them sit nicely in the middle regardless of the `img` or carousel image height.